# How to evaluate impact of two independent variables on one dependent variable in a sample

Tags: statistics

I have two independent variables named x and y which are impacting on a third variable called $z$. It means that $z=ax+by$. I have done $900$ experiments and would like to know the mean value of $a$ and $b$. I am looking for the name of test or analysis that I should perform in preferably SPSS or any other relevant application. I appreciate your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you collect your measurements $x_i$ and $y_i$ in a matrix

$${\bf X} = \left (\array{x_1\quad y_1\\x_2\quad y_2\\\vdots\\x_N\quad y_N} \right)$$

then your overdetermined system of equations is given by

$$\bf Xa = z$$

with ${\bf a} = (a,b)^T$ your vector of unknowns, and with ${\bf z}=(z_1,\ldots,z_N)^T$. The optimal least squares solution for $\bf a$ is then given by

$${\bf a} = ({\bf X}^T{\bf X})^{-1}{\bf X}^T{\bf z}$$

You can use Matlab or Octave to compute the solution. Of course you can also use SPSS, but I don't know how this function is called in SPSS.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Should I calculate all 'x' and 'y' manually or does Matlab take care of it?

Comment: I thought that $x$, $y$, and $z$ are your measurements. If you have them as vectors in Matlab or Octave, then you can write X=[x(:),y(:)] and z = z(:) (to make sure your vectors are column vectors). Then you can compute $\bf a$ using Y=X'*X; a = (X'*z)\Y;